# Alpha Beta Pruning Breaking Minimax

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chess, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

So I implemented a minimax search for my chess based puzzle game. In this case the search determines the AI pieces next move.

The minimax on it's own works fine it returns the expected move but when I implement alpha beta pruning the minimax returns the same two values for each piece every turn. 
For example an AI Rook currently at (0,0) may receive (1,0) as it's move from the minimax and next time it asks the minimax for it's move it will receive (0,0). This loop happens no matter what I change in the evaluation function.

The game state consists of the user's location, the piece's location and the array of tiles which represents the board itself. 
I use my own node class (should really be called Pair) here in order to store each Tile with it's respective value given by the evaluation function.

Is there an issue with how I'm implemented my alpha beta pruning? Any advice is greatly appreciated. If more information is needed just ask and I'll provide what I can.

```
//Here is my call to the minimax
Min(depth, user, piece, new Node((int) (Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)), new Node((int) Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY), tiles));

Node Max(int depth, Piece user, Piece piece, Node alpha, Node beta, Tile[][] tiles)
{
    if(depth <= 0||gameOver(piece))
    {
        return new Node(evaluation(user,piece,tiles));
    }
    LinkedList<Tile> moves = user.getMoves(tiles,1);
    for(Tile t:moves)
    {
        Tile temp= new Tile(user);
        tiles= user.changePos(t,tiles);
        Node val = Min(depth - 1, user, piece, alpha, beta, tiles);
        val.addTile(t);
        tiles= user.changePos(temp,tiles);
        if(val.getValue()>=beta.getValue())
            return beta;
        if(val.getValue() >= alpha.getValue())
        {
            if(alpha.getTile()==null)
                alpha = val;
            else if(val.getValue()==alpha.getValue()){
                if(r.nextInt(2)==1)//adds an element of randomness 
                    alpha=val;
            }
            else
                alpha=val;
        }
    }
    return alpha;
}
Node Min(int depth, Piece user, Piece piece, Node alpha, Node beta, Tile[][] tiles)
{
    updateGoal(user);
    if(depth <= 0||gameOver(piece))
    {
        return new Node(evaluation(user,piece,tiles));
    }
    LinkedList<Tile> moves = piece.getMoves(tiles,1);
    for(Tile t:moves)
    {

        Tile temp= new Tile(piece);
        tiles= piece.changePos(t,tiles);
        Node val = Max(depth - 1, user, piece, alpha, beta,tiles);
        val.addTile(t);
        tiles= piece.changePos(temp,tiles);
        if(val.getValue() <= alpha.getValue())
            return alpha;
        if(val.getValue() <= beta.getValue())
        {
            if(beta.getTile()==null)
                beta = val;
            else if(val.getValue()==beta.getValue()){
                if(r.nextInt(2)==1)
                    beta=val;
            }
            else
                beta=val;
        }
    }
    return beta;
}
```

Comment: Did you call it with the correct initial alpha and beta values? Generally, the way to debug something like this is to create a simple test case on paper and then single-step in a debugger to see where the code deviates from the theory.

Comment: It's very hard to debug by just reading the code like this. Anyway, it's not common that a chess engine is implemented by max-min. Everybody uses nega-max. Nega-max allows you to shorten your code to one single function.

Comment: ... and don't use NEGATIVE_INFINITY with a negamax function - because -NEGATIVE_INFINITY causes an overflow error and all sorts of strange problems. I'd go with +/- 1,000,000 or similar to keep things simple.

Comment: I bet the compiler warns you about using `Tile[][]` as a parameter. If you fix that, it might work better.